# How to make the color of the number green when its greater than 0, red when less than 0, and black when its 0;

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener

i tried to increase the number of the valueHolder variable when the user click the increase button and make the color green, the first condition happen but the color get green even its less than 0 or equal to 0;
i want to increase the number and alongside number the color should get green according to the conditions which i set.

```
const valueHolder = document.getElementById("value");
const decreaseBtn = document.getElementById("decrease");

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", increaseNumber);

function increaseNumber(){
   valueHolder.innerText ++;
   if(valueHolder.innerText > 0){
      valueHolder.style.color = "green";
   }else if(valueHolder.innerText < 0){
valueHolder.style.color = "red";
}else{
valueHolder.style.color = "black";
}
}
```

Comment: `valueHolder.innerText` is a string, comparing strings can give you unexpected results.

Comment: Did you add an event listener for `decreaseBtn`? If so, could you share it with us?

Comment: Please provide your full code or any codesandbox link to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Teemu, although i convert it to number using Number() method, but still doesn't work

Comment: Neha Soni, sure i added event listener but once I'm ok with increaseBtn then I can do the same for decreaseBtn where both have the same code flow